# Fill a path with image and stretch image in Canvas HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I wanna to fill a path like a circle or a custom path with an image but wanna the image to stretch, so that the pixels of the image don't reside outside the closed path.
Is this possible to achieve in HTML5 using the Canvas object ?

Here is my custom path:

```
ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(170, 80);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

    // complete custom shape
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;

    ctx.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.stroke();
```

What I wanna to achieve is to fill the cloud with an image but stretch it. Doesn't matter if it look ugly.

Comment: yes. Do you have a code example of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Edit based on more info from OP]**

**ima.js**, is a small image script that will combine 2 images like this:

[image]

Into a single warp-envelope image like this using canvas:

[image]

You can see a demo at: http://ima.hobby.infi.nl/#

And the script is available at: http://ima.hobby.infi.nl/ima.js

---

**[Previous answer before OP added more info]**

You can clip an image inside of a path.

And yes, you can "stretch" an undersized image like this:

```
context.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/T4eN8/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw the cloud
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(170, 80);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.stroke();

    // clip any subsequent draws to the cloud
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(170, 80);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();

    // draw an image inside the cloud
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,img.width,img.height);
    }
    img.src="http://www.gcc.edu/_layouts/GCC/Backgrounds/1024.jpg";

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. That's not exactly what I'm searching for. I don't wanna to simply put the image in the path but I wanna that the image border follow the path and is stretched accordingly to the path border. Is this possible?

Comment: OK....that looks like the "envelope warp" effect in Adobe Illustrator.  There is a canvas library that does warp effect, too.  Check out this blog post by the author of the library: http://code.almeros.com/water-ripple-canvas-and-javascript#.UTEr-7so6Uk

Comment: The link to the script `ima.js` is broken, is there anywhere I can find it ?